# jQuery ajax call failing in Zend

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I set up an zend controller to handle partial HTML for ajax requests and whenever I access it directly it works just fine, but when I access it via an ajax call it gives a 500 error. I am not sure where to begin looking to try to figure out what is failing. I completely turned off all acl stuff and it still fails.

access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Dec/2012:16:31:04 -0500] "GET /ajax/iconlist?icondir=attributes&format=html HTTP/1.1" 500 1157 "http://hc.localhost/attribute/edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Dec/2012:16:32:08 -0500] "GET /ajax/iconlist?icondir=attributes&format=html HTTP/1.1" 200 1757 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
```

The first entry is a the ajax request which fails with 500. The second is going to the link directly which loads just fine.

Tre`

Comment: what are the request and response details in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're running into cross domain issues with ajax. It's trying to access http://hc.localhost/ rather than localhost or 127.0.0.1 and maybe that causes it to fail.

JSON-P comes up a lot if you search for "cross domain ajax" so perhaps it's worth a look

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I don't think it's a cross domain issue because if I point it at just the root page for example, it loads it just fine.